# Java GAE, openid4java fails while doing discovery on google, Permission Denied

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-openid, openid4java

I am using Openid4Java to implement Openid for my app on GAE. I am also using Shiro for security. The day before i had reached a stage where things were failing for credentials matching, i.e discovery, making auth request, getting claimed_id were all working.
Yesterday all hell broke lose and since then discovery on Google is failing. 
things that i have verified:

- Yahoo is working fine (end to end)and
- Discovery for google is working fine on my local dev box(it ofcourse fails while returning to my localhost URL).
- The application on appengine has billing enabled so that internally Yadis can open socket connections.

I have tried the following discovery urls for Google:
(some URLS below have spaces because i cant post more than 2 links). they are fine otherwise.

- https: //www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
- https: //www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID?hl=es-ES#endpoint)

A few interesting logs before the stack trace:

```
org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery discover: Starting discovery on URL identifier: https: //www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver retrieveXrdsLocation: Performing HTTP HEAD on: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id ...

org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1 getConnection: Get connection: {s}->https://www.google.com, timeout = 3000

org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute getEntryBlocking: [{s}->https://www.google.com] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 20

org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute getFreeEntry: No free connections [{s}->https://www.google.com][null]

org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute getEntryBlocking: Available capacity: 2 out of 2 [{s}->https://www.google.com][null]

org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute createEntry: Creating new connection [{s}->https://www.google.com]

org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator openConnection: Connecting to www.google.com:443

org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection close: Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@197d562 closed
```

the stack trace is as follows:

```
org.apache.shiro.openid4j.DiscoveryException: Unable to discover OpenId Provider based on resolved discoveryId 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id' (specified providerId 'null')
at org.apache.shiro.openid4j.DefaultOpenIdService.getDiscoveryInfo(DefaultOpenIdService.java:182)
at org.apache.shiro.openid4j.DefaultOpenIdService.constructRequestFromOpenIdUrl(DefaultOpenIdService.java:123)
at org.apache.shiro.openid4j.authc.Open4jFilter.constructOpenIdRequest(Open4jFilter.java:344)
at org.apache.shiro.openid4j.authc.Open4jFilter.executeOpenidLogin(Open4jFilter.java:327)
at org.apache.shiro.openid4j.authc.Open4jFilter.onAccessDenied(Open4jFilter.java:304)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.AccessControlFilter.onAccessDenied(AccessControlFilter.java:133)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.AccessControlFilter.onPreHandle(AccessControlFilter.java:162)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.PathMatchingFilter.isFilterChainContinued(PathMatchingFilter.java:203)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.PathMatchingFilter.preHandle(PathMatchingFilter.java:178)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:131)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisException: 0x704: I/O transport error: Permission denied: Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission. (mapped-IPv4)
at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:479)
at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:249)
at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:233)
at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:167)
at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:147)
at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:129)
at org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.discover(ConsumerManager.java:568)
at org.apache.shiro.openid4j.DefaultOpenIdService.getDiscoveryInfo(DefaultOpenIdService.java:178)
... 49 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission. (mapped-IPv4)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.translateError(SocketApiHelper.java:107)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.translateError(SocketApiHelper.java:118)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.makeSyncCall(SocketApiHelper.java:82)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.connectSocket(AppEngineSocketImpl.java:421)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AppEngineSocketImpl.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.connect(AppEngineSocketImpl.java:352)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:600)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:623)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:549)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:151)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
at org.openid4java.util.HttpCache.head(HttpCache.java:336)
at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:401)
... 56 more
```

the relying party code is pretty similar to the SampleConsumer (part of openid4java) but is actually a patch on shiro(openid4j). It seems to be in accordance with Sample Consumer.

Seems to me that i am missing something basic here. Any pointers will really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the libraries you use are failing when trying to make connections to `www.google.com:443`.

Sockets API has [quite a few limitations](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/#limitations-and-restrictions), most notably it does not allow connections to google servers (with some exceptions for email & DNS). This is a source of your errors.

If you want your app to use OpenID for auth then just use GAE provided APIs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid

Comment: Thanks Peter!! You sent me on the right track. No more permission denied. I used a non-socket approach. Will also try and look at a more simpler solution.